# Qt C++ connect signal with non-void signature to lambda

Tags: c++, qt, lambda, connect, qobject

I want to connect a signal with non-void signature to a lambda function.
My code looks like the following

`QTimeLine *a = new QTimeLine(DURATION, this);
connect(a, &QTimeLine::valueChanged, [a,this](qreal r) mutable { this->setMaximumHeight(r);});`

in a way similar to the SIGNAL-SLOT approach:

`connect(a, SIGNAL(valueChanged(qreal),this,SLOT(doStuff(qreal)));`

My connect-to-lambda compiles, but it won't change `this->height()`.
What did I get wrong? How should I write the lambda so that it takes the `qreal` from `valueChanged`?
I read the related documentation, but I couldn't find useful examples.

****EDIT****

In fact it works, I was getting the QTimeLine settings wrong. And yes, I don't need to capture `a`.
I was trying to animate a custom `insertRow()` method of a QTableWidget. 
I also made the lambda change the height of the table row instead of the contained widget's. For reference, here's the working snippet:

```
QTimeLine *a = new QTimeLine(DURATION,this);
connect(a,&QTimeLine::valueChanged,[this](qreal r) mutable {
     this->list->setRowHeight(0,r * ROW::HEIGHT);
     });
a->start();
```

Thanks a lot for the quick replies anyway.

Comment: What `connect` returns? What errors it writes to the Output?

Comment: Can you please provide some self-contained code that we can compile? I wrote one for myself, and I cannot reproduce the issue, so I assume my code is different...

Comment: It __should__ work perfectly fine. Check if your signal really connects with the lambda, and that the lambda really gets called. Also, I fail to understand why does your lambda need to capture `a`.

Comment: In addition, does your "old variant" work, i.e. just to make sure you are using QTimeLine properly so that the signal is emitted.

Comment: Why is the lambda mutable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should just work. Here is a complete SSCCE that demonstrates it working. Check what you are doing different in principles.

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QTimeLine>
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QCoreApplication>

class Foo
{
    void setMaximumHeight(int h) {height = h; qDebug() << "Height:" << height;}
    public:
    void doStuff() { QObject::connect(&timeLine, &QTimeLine::valueChanged, [this](qreal r) mutable { setMaximumHeight(r);}); timeLine.start(); }
    int maximumHeight() const { return height; }
    int height{0};
    int DURATION{100};
    QTimeLine timeLine{DURATION};
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QCoreApplication application(argc, argv);
    Foo foo;
    foo.doStuff();
    return application.exec();
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && make && ./main
```